# How to properly write e2e tests of Vuetify apps?

Tags: nightwatch.js, vuetify.js, e2e-testing

Currently I am using Nightwatch.js with Chromedriver to perform e2e tests of my Vuetify app. However, the test results are indeterministic.

Many times I get errors like: `Timed out while waiting for element <.menuable__content__active> to be present for 5000 milliseconds.` when running `waitForElementVisible('.menuable__content__active', 5000)` right after `click('.v-select')`, whereas sometimes it passes.

There must be a simpler way to select an item in `<v-select>` other than clicking on it, waiting for `.menuable__content__active` and clicking on `.menuable__content__active .v-list__tile--link`. The same with `<v-menu>`, `<v-autocomplete>`, `<v-date-picker>`, etc.

Other times running `click('#myid .v-btn')` does not work, but `execute('document.querySelector("#myid .v-btn").click()')` does.

What is the proper way to do deterministic e2e testing of Vuetify apps with a lot of dynamic components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to successfully e2e-test Vuetify using **[Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/)** instead of Nightwatch.js, which implicitly waits for elements to appear when using `cy.get()`. Moreover, its snapshots in between tests are really useful for debugging.